# Unpredictable collision between 2 arrays

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am currently building a game in AndEngine, but my collision detection seems a bit off. It works.. most of the time, but seems like when there is a collision with one object, it wont do the other. It's hard to explain and it's very unpredictable. If a car hits the snow, it should slow down. If a car hits ice, it should speed up.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rManager.carArray.length; i++)
{
if (rManager.getInstance().snowArray[0].getSnowSprite().collidesWith(rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarSprite()))
{
    Log.e("SNOW", "snow 0 collided with " + rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].ToString());
    rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].setCarSpeed(0.1f);
    break;
}

if (rManager.getInstance().iceArray[0].getIceSprite().collidesWith(rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarSprite()))
{
    Log.e("ICE", "ice 0 collided with " + rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].ToString());
    rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].setCarSpeed(1f);
    break;
}

else
{
    rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].setCarSpeed(0.5f);
}
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Currently, both enemy arrays only have 1 element. That is why I am only checking 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `break;` within the collision detection `if` test. (Or change it to continue if you only want snow or ice but not both for the same car...not sure quite how your game works in that regard).